# Infinitely many quadratic extension fields of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I'm working on this problem:

Find infinitely many quadratic extension fields of $\mathbb{Q}$ that are pairwise non isomorphic, and prove that they are indeed pairwise non isomorphic.

So far, I found that there are infinitely many $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ , where $n$ is a prime number. Now I'm stuck at a showing $\phi : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ is not an isomorphism, for any distinct prime $n$ and $m$.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: If $\sqrt{m} = a+b\sqrt{n}$ then $m= a^2+b^2n+2ab \sqrt{n}$

Comment: Can you show that the equation $x^2=m$ has no solutions in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt n)$? You may have seen a proof of $\sqrt3\notin\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$? You can mimick that!

Comment: @reuns, I don't that disproves the existence of an isomorphism? That shows they are not equal

Comment: @mathworker21 replace $\sqrt{m}$ by "a root of $x^2-m$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$" (which obviously you will denote by $\sqrt{m}$)

Comment: Kummer theory${}$?

Comment: You can take the fields $\Bbb Q(\sqrt p\,)$ just for the $p\equiv3\pmod4$. In each case the ring of algebraic integers is $\Bbb Z[\sqrt p\,]$, with discriminant $4p$, which is certainly an invariant of the field. I personally think, @LordSharktheUnknown, that Kummer Theory is more advanced than necessary.

Comment: @Lubin From the OP's statement, it should be straightforward to construct the isomorphism $\psi : \{ K/\mathbb{Q}, [K: \mathbb{Q}] = 2 \} \to \mathbb{Q}^* /(\mathbb{Q}^* )^2$

Comment: Well, @reuns, I supose it’s easy enough to construct a map, but then you need to show that it does what it’s supposed to. Doesn’t that amount to, for instance, showing that there’s no square root of $2$ in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3\,)$?

Comment: @Lubin Given $[K: \mathbb{Q}] = 2, K = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+bx+c) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{b^2-4c})$ I would set $\psi(K) = \{ \delta \in \mathbb{Q}^*, \sqrt{\delta} \in K\}$. Then OP's statement generalizes to $\psi(K) = (b^2-4c) (\mathbb{Q}^*)^2$

Comment: I think you’re probably right, @reuns, but can you use this to persuade OP that $\sqrt2\notin\Bbb Q(\sqrt3\,)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p$ and $q$ be distnct primes. Suppose $\phi \colon {\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{p})\to {\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{q})$ is an isomorphism. Suppose $\phi(\sqrt{p})=a+b\sqrt{q}$.  Then, since $\phi$ is identity on $\Bbb Q$, it follows that $p=\phi(p)=(a+b\sqrt{q})^2$. You can easily get a contradiction from this.